# Function calls in OpenMP loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have been trying to parallelize a particle simulation code I wrote. But in my parallelization, I came away with no increase in performance when moving from 1 processor to 12, and even worse the code is no longer returning accurate results. I have been banging my head against the wall and can't figure this out. Below is the loop being parallelized:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
omp_set_dynamic(1);
omp_set_num_threads(12);

#pragma omp for
// Loop over azimuth ejection angle, from 0-360.
for(int i=0; i<360; i++)
{
    // Declare temporary variables
    double *y = new double[12];
    vector<double> ejecVel(3); 
    vector<double> colLoc(7);
    double azimuth, inc;
    bool collision; 

    // Loop over inclincation ejection angle from 1-max_angle, increasing by 1 degree. 
    for(int j=1; j<=15; j++)
    {
        // Update azimuth and inclination angle and get velocity direction vector.
        azimuth   = (double) i;
        inc       = (double) j;
        ejecVel   = Jet::GetEjecVelocity(azimuth,inc);
        collision = false;

        // Update initial conditions. 
        y[0]  = m_parPos[0];
        y[1]  = m_parPos[1];
            ... (define pointer values)

        // Simulate particle
        systemSolver.ParticleSim(simSteps,dt,y,collision,colLoc);

        if(collision == true)
        {
            cout << "Collision! " << endl;
        }
    }
    delete [] y; 
}
```

The goal is to loop through, simulating particles for different initial conditions over the loops, and store where they have gone and their state vector upon collision in master variables densCount and collisionStates. The simulation takes place in a function from another class (systemSolver.ParticleSim() ), and it seems like each solve from a different thread is not independent. Everything I've read suggests that it should be, but I can't figure out why else the result would not be right only if I have Open MP implemented. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

-ben

---

SOLUTION: The simulation was modifying a member variable of a separate (systemSolver) class. Since I provided a single class object to all threads, they were all simultaneously modifying an important member variable. Thought I would post this in case any other n00bs encounter a similar problem.

Comment: How do you define your result being accurate and correct? By comparing `collisionStates` from the serial case to the parallel case? If so then you can't expect them to be the same. The values should be the same but the order will likely not be the same.

Comment: There's both too much and not enough code here for us to nail down the problem; can you whittle the code to a [minimum complete valid example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Also, while irrelevant to your question, I assume inc should be j, not i?

Comment: @Zboson I defined 'accurate' by checking for particles having collided. If I loop through a set when there should be a notable number of collisions (and there are without Open MP), in the Open MP loop there are zero collisions.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I'll try to fix the code provided. Yes, inc should be j not i, that happened while I was trying to reduce the code to a minimal, helpful example...

Answer (score 1):

I believe one mistake is the call to omp_set_* functions inside the parallel region. In the best case, they take effect on subsequent regions only. Try to reorder as following:

```
omp_set_dynamic(1);
omp_set_num_threads(12);
#pragma omp parallel
```